# Kotlin-Java interop not working with varargs

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm

I wanted to abstract out getting resources in Android, so I have written a class `ResourceProvider` that actually provides resources:

```
@Singleton
class ResourceProvider @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {
fun getString(@StringRes id: Int): String {
    return context.getString(id)
}

fun getString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): String {
    return context.getString(id, formatArgs)
}
...
}
```

Nothing special here, just calling methods on `Context`. 
I have a problem when I want to get String with parameters, I created following example:

```
var fromContext = requireContext().getString(R.string.one_parameter_string, "Text")
Log.i("fromContext", fromContext)
var fromWrapper = resourceProvider.getString(R.string.one_parameter_string, "Text")
Log.i("fromWrapper", fromWrapper)

fromContext = requireContext().getString(R.string.two_parameter_string, "Text", "Text")
Log.i("fromContext", fromContext)
fromWrapper = resourceProvider.getString(R.string.two_parameter_string, "Text", "Text")
Log.i("fromWrapper", fromWrapper)
```

Here are String resources:

```
<string formatted="false" name="two_parameter_string">Text with parameters: %s, %s</string>
<string formatted="false" name="one_parameter_string">Text with parameter: %s</string>
```

as you can see I'm calling the same methods directly on `Context` and on my `ResourceProvider` class. I would expect the same results, but in fact this is what is printed in console:

```
I/fromContext: Text with parameter: Text
I/fromWrapper: Text with parameter: [Ljava.lang.Object;@6d43f06
I/fromContext: Text with parameters: Text, Text
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 22963
    java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2522)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2814)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:472)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:572)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.ResourceProvider.getString(ResourceProvider.kt:21)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.views.trial.TrialFragment.onViewCreated(TrialFragment.kt:45)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

As you can see calling it directly on `Context` works without the flaws, but calling the same method with my wrapper makes it print `Object.toString()` and in second case it crashes.

Here is the decompiled version of the `getString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any)` method:

```
@NotNull
public final String getString(@StringRes int id, @NotNull Object... formatArgs) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(formatArgs, "formatArgs");
  String var10000 = this.context.getString(id, new Object[]{formatArgs});
  Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(var10000, "context.getString(id, formatArgs)");
  return var10000;
}
```

What is the problem and how to avid it?

Comment: I also experienced this issue. +1 for asking this question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the spread operator (`*`) to call `context.getString`, i.e. you need to use `*formatArgs`:

```
@Singleton
class ResourceProvider @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {
  fun getString(@StringRes id: Int): String {
    return context.getString(id)
  }

  fun getString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): String {
    return context.getString(id, *formatArgs)
  }
...
}
```

You can read more about it in the [kotlin reference regarding variable number of arguments (varargs)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs).

If you don't do it, then the given object (in this case a `formatArgs`-array) is treated as a single object which you want to pass to the `vararg`-method, which will therefore be wrapped into a `Object[] { formatArgs }`.

Comment: This probably saved me days of frustration.  Thank you!